# Use callback without consider instance function or not

Tags: python

The following code:

```
def foo(a):
    print(a)


class A(object):
    callback = foo
    def do(self):
        self.callback(1)


A().do()
```

Produce following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bastien/Projects/test/t.py", line 13, in <module>
    A().do()
  File "/home/bastien/Projects/test/t.py", line 10, in do
    self.callback(1)
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Because `foo` function is used like an instance function. I can add a `@staticmethod` decorator on `foo` function but: Is there a way to "adapt" behaviour of `A.do` without touch `foo` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling it with `self` when `callback` it is not part of the **instance** but the **class**, try doing:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.callback = foo
    def do(self):
        self.callback(1)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/KGFR)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `lambda` to wrap your function

```
def foo(a):
    print(a)

class A(object):
    callback = (lambda self, x: foo(x))
    def do(self):
        self.callback(1)


A().do()
```